# Unit Test Windsor Controller Factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, castle-windsor

I am struggling to unit test the following piece of code. It is the controller factory for initializing the mvc controllers in an application. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to unit test it?

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        this.kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }

        return (IController)this.kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward, does it really need to be tested?

Comment: I would say probably not, however I have been requested to get coverage as high as possible so I thought I would ask the question.

Comment: What is the value of 3 lines coverage that you will see immediately they are broken (if it ever happen). I don't see any. Focus on parts that are critical and fragile.

Comment: I am suppose to get > 80% coverage, but as I get close I'm finding most of the code remaining is like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless you decide to override

IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)

your test become more complex because original CreateController calls GetControllerType

Said so, I have to agree with Ales... but if you really have to... you can easly unit test kernel invocation using a mocking framework such Moq

Let say you want test ReleaseController method

```
var controller = new Mock<IController>();
var kernel= new Mock<IKernel>();
var windsorControllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(kernel.Object);
windsorControllerFactory.ReleaseController(controller.Object);
kernel.Verify(m => m.ReleaseComponent(controller.Object));
```